# Error in function that returns a struct in c: expected identifier or '(' before paramter

Tags: c, function, struct, declaration, definition

I am new to c, and I'm trying to make a function that takes two parameters of type double as input, and returns a struct containing each parameter as members called "real" and imaginary. The error I am getting is:

```
error: expected identifier or ‘(’ before ‘double’
```

The error is pointing to the line in which I define the function. I am aware that there are other posts covering this same error, but as far as I can tell, this is not the same issue as in those (and apologies if it is).

Here is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    return 0;
}

struct make_complex(double real_input, double imaginary_input) {

    struct complex {
        double real;
        double imaginary;
    } complex_output = {real_input, imaginary_input};

    return complex_output; 
}
```

I eventually want to call the make_complex function in main, but I have simplified main completely as to eliminate any other source of error. I have tried declaring the make_complex function before the function definition like so:

```
struct make_complex(double real_input, double imaginary_input);
```

This didn't work. Ideas?

Thanks for your time.

Comment: `struct make_complex()` is gibberish. You need to study struct before using struct.

Answer (score 3):

The return type of the function needs to includes the structure type, not just `struct`. And you should define the structure type outside the function so it can be referenced in the callers.

```
#include <stdio.h>

struct complex {
    double real;
    double imaginary;
};

int main(void) {
    return 0;
}

struct complex make_complex(double real_input, double imaginary_input) {
    struct complex complex_output = {real_input, imaginary_input};
    return complex_output; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In this function declaration

```
struct make_complex(double real_input, double imaginary_input) {
```

the compiler considers this line as a declaration of a structure with the name `make_complex`.

You need to define the structure complex before the function declaration as for example

```
struct complex {
    double real;
    double imaginary;
};

struct complex make_complex(double real_input, double imaginary_input) {

    struct complex complex_output = {real_input, imaginary_input};

    return complex_output; 
}
```

In C you even may define the structure in the declaration of the function return type

```
struct complex { double real; double imaginary; }
make_complex(double real_input, double imaginary_input) {
    struct complex complex_output = {real_input, imaginary_input};

    return complex_output; 
}
```

though it is not a good idea.:)

Comment: @user3629249 If the return type is not specified then the declaration is incorrect.

Comment: also, please note that `double complex' is a valid type in modern C

Comment: @user3629249 It is implementation defined whether the compiler supports the type

Comment: @user3629249 I have not understood your question about the signature because such a declaration is present in my answer.

Comment: I read it too fast and missed the detail of their not being a semicolon at the end of the struct definition